# Altbeacon - Scan multiple UUID in an array

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy, altbeacon

I'm using [Altbeacon](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/index.html) library for my app to scan for beacons. I've had success in scanning and pushing a notification when there is an advertisement. My requirement is I need to scan a list of UUIDs, but the example given in the docs is using only one UUID to scan.

Here is what I did so far, I put the BeaconConsumer in my BaseActivity so that it starts scanning immediately after launch (No background scanning):

```
public class BaseActivity extends SlidingFragmentActivity implements BeaconConsumer {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ...

        beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
        beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
                setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
        beaconManager.bind(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
        beaconManager.setMonitorNotifier(new MonitorNotifier() {
            @Override
            public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BeaconNotificationService.class);
                intent.putExtra("uuid", region.getId1().toString());
                intent.putExtra("major", region.getId2().toString());
                intent.putExtra("minor", region.getId3().toString());
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startService(intent);
            }

            @Override
            public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
                Log.i(TAG, "I no longer see any beacon");
            }

            @Override
            public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int state, Region region) {
                Log.i(TAG, "I have just switched from seeing/not seeing beacons: "+state);
            }
        });

        try {
            beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(new Region("com.my.app.boostrapRegion",
                    Identifier.parse(Constants.BT_UUID),
                    Identifier.fromInt(Constants.BT_MAJOR),
                    Identifier.fromInt(Constants.BT_MINOR)));
        } catch (RemoteException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }

}
```

In Constants class, I defined my UUID for testing purpose:

```
public class Constants {

    public static final String BT_UUID = "bbbbbbbb-3443-8888-3443-bb323bbb0005";
    public static final int BT_MAJOR = 0;
    public static final int BT_MINOR = 0;

}
```

How do I put, let's say, an array of UUIDs to be scanned by the BeaconConsumer?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of defining a UUID in the region, you can add `null`, to find all beacons in range. You can then later on filter out the beacons you're looking for.
In this example I left your major and minor ids intact, for clarity purposes.

```
try {
    beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(new Region("com.my.app.boostrapRegion",
    null,
    Identifier.fromInt(Constants.BT_MAJOR),
    Identifier.fromInt(Constants.BT_MINOR)));
} catch (RemoteException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```